# Popup alignment

Tags: jquery, popup

I have created a popup using jQuery..

I have 4 `div` tags in my html page, and after that the div tag which contains the popup matter is present.

When I click on a link, the popup is getting displayed below the 4 div tags ..and one has to scroll to see the popup

Is there any property to change in the css so that the popup comes above the div tags...??

Can anyone help me with this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup it's possible, have a look at the [Position property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp).

There's a good tutorial on positioning from w3schools here: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

If you post your code in your original question, we could provide more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning for this. Use `.css()` to style the div and give a `left` and `top` value.